# How to fix "A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation."

Tags: java, command

I have written a Java program on Eclipse and I'm able to run the program. But when I transfer it to Notepad++ and run it via command  prompt. It gave me an ERROR message. Any idea on how to solve it?

I have attach an image of the error.

[image: "Error Message"]

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Assignment_2 has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown 
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown 
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown 
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown 
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown 
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown 
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native 
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown 
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown 
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown 
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown 
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Please insert the whole error into this question from image that you attached

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message tells you that the class version is different. In other words, the Java compiler you used in Eclipse is newer than the Java runtime you use in the command prompt. You should check which Java version you want then use only this version. To change the version you use in the command prompt you must change the `path` environment variable to contain the path to the desired version. In Eclipse you can select the used version in the settings.

Comment: Hi Jannik, I just checked the version used for both my Eclipse and command prompt . Both used the same version.

Comment: Are you entirely sure? If you run `java -version` it should tell you that you run Java 11.

Comment: Yes yes, i checked the version. both using Java 11.0.2

Comment: And the error message is still the same? I can't quite believe this because the error you are seeing is quite common and always indicates a mismatch between compiled version and runtime version. Additionally, Java 11 should be able to run version 55 bytecode.

Comment: sorry I got mixed up with `%PATH%` and `java - version`. When I `java -version`, it showed `java version "1.8.0_231"`. When I `%PATH%`, it showed `11.0.2` So it's wrong version. My Eclipse is using version 11.0.2. Please guide me on how to change the path on my command prompt. Thank you

Comment: You are on windows I'd guess. Go to the search and type `Edit the system environment variables`. This opens a dialog window where you need to click on `Environment variables`. Then you can edit the variables to your desire. When you've finished editing you must restart the command prompt.

Comment: Yes i did add a new `Environment variables` linking it to `java version 11.0.2` however when I `java -version`, the version displayed is still `1.8.0_231`. I did restart my command prompt.

Comment: You must edit the `path` variable and add the path there. Also, make sure that you remove the old java version from your path or add your newer version before the old version. Otherwise you'll still see the old version. Also note, that there are two path variables, one for the system and one for the user. It doesn't really matter where you add the new version, but you must check both of them to remove the old Java version.

Comment: I did deleted the old version and added new path variable linking it to java 11.0.2. However when I `java -version`, everything is the same, same error message. Have no idea where I do wrong.

Comment: Hmm, it's difficult to find the root cause in this fashion and I don't really know what to  tell you anymore. So I'd recommend that you go to your `path` variables and remove everything that contains `java` or `jdk`. Now `java -version` shouldn't work anymore. If it still works you haven't removed the correct thing from the path (go back and remove it :D). When it is removed successfully add the path to your JDK\bin folder to the `path` and the JDK folder to `java_home`. Now you should be able to use the correct Java version.

Comment: Thank you. I managed to solve the problem by listening to your guidance.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same issue but the reason why i was faing that of because I had created a package name called Java and when tried to ran my class getting -a-jni-error-has-occurred

But after going through error logs I found Java package name is prohibited , so I changed my package name and it worked for me

Comment: This is the same answer as @Unique 's answer.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this error due to the folder name which I had named as java. Then as I renamed the folder in which my java programs were kept, it worked fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer kind of guided me towards a solution.
The package I was using was named `java.example.java`, just changed for `com.example.java` and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the Java 11 installer defaults the set JAVA_HOME variable and the JavaSoft registration variable to exclude (red cross). Ensure that you select both to add full feature. Complete Java install and then reinstall application.
Voila !!!

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/76Ymh.png)